# How to add a ExchangeRateProvider to javax.money

Tags: java, spring, serviceloader, java-money

I wrote a custom ExchangeRateProvider that needs dependency injection. But for java.money you need to add your custom class in a file under **META-INF/services/javax.money.convert.ExchangeRateProvider**.
The normal ServiceLoader does not use dependency injection.

I use spring, so my idea is to use the spring context for the dependency management and then add it to the java.money context.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?